# mainframe in Joomla

Tags: joomla

The [hello world tutorial](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/773/125/) for Joomla states:

> $mainframe is a global variable in
>   Joomla that has lots of useful methods
>   attached to it.

How do I find out what these methods are? I tried searching through their documentation, but I couldn't find any clues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$mainframe` object is ultimately an instance the `JApplication` class. The `JApplication` class is defined in `libraries/joomla/application/application.php`. Depending on whether you're in the administrator or frontend section of Joomla, the `$mainframe` object is a direct instance of `JAdministrator` or `JSite` respectively. These classes are in `includes/application.php` and `administrator/includes/application.php`.

Comment: I searched the [class tree](http://api.joomla.org/classtrees_Joomla-Framework.html), but I can't find a a JSite or JAdministrator class

Comment: That's where the divide between the CMS and the Framework lies. The class tree is showing *only* the framework. The $mainframe object gets defined in index.php at the application (CMS) level. I'm not finding any specific documentation on JSite or JAdministrator, but they both extend JApplication.

Comment: @jileblanc: Do JSite or JAdministrator have any extra functions or are we supposed to just access them through the JApplication interface?

Comment: Most of the functions in JSite and JAdministrator appear to be overrides of JApplication, but there are a few that appear only to be in JSite (like authorize()). It looks like there's some documentation missing here http://docs.joomla.org/JAdministrator and here http://docs.joomla.org/JSite. But there is documentation on JApplication here http://docs.joomla.org/JApplication.

Comment: @jleb: If you use the @ when replying and at least the first 4 characters of the name then the other person will receive an alert that you have replied

Comment: I decided to post a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604889/japplication-jadministrator-in-joomla) specifically on these classes

Answer (score 5):

In joomla 2.5 global $mainframe is not accessible via global $mainframe.
 Use following code instead of global $mainframe.

```
$mainframe=JFactory::getApplication();
```

Visit this URl for more info

https://bitbucket.org/joomla/joomla-platform/raw/247ba8d88526096394c44dee8b9e5f4c7e315afc/libraries/joomla/application/application.php