# JSite, JAdministrator in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I can find documentation for their super class JApplication, but I can't find documentation for either of these classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where there is any online documentation but I can tell you where they are defined:

**JSite:** [site root]/includes/application.php

**JAdministrator:** [site root]/administrator/includes/application.php

Answer (score 1):

http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Application/JApplication.html - but you have probably seen it already.

Most of the publicly available documentation is very poor, but I found this book useful: Mastering Joomla! 1.5 Extension and Framework Development

Comment: I accidentally wrote JApplication, instead of JSite.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Joomla has always some changes in joomla-API in each version so, it's depends on version what is the flow of document reference.

I use joomla 2.5 here i'm sharing a link plz follow if you get an idea.
http://doc.joomladev.eu/api25/

Find this class in:
libraries/joomla/application/application.php

other classes also found in libraries folder.